# Favicon using wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, favicon

I am trying to change favicon in wordpress. For which i have uploaded image in media and in theme customisation, under site identity i used that image as a favicon.

Which is displaying in my admin panel but not in website browser. I tried to inspect it, so it is showing me below line but not coming image name in href

```
<link rel="icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">
```

So for that i need to change my each php file's head with appropriate code that is

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://my_url/image" sizes="32x32" />
```

but my question is, is there anyway where i can directly change it without going to all the pages' header in wordpress.

I also tried clearing cache and all the other solution, but not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your wordpress version is 4.2+, just add `wp_head()` in your `header.php` between `<head>` tags:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

You should be able to change the favicon from Administration Screen > Appearance > Customize now.

Function reference: [wp_head()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/)

Comment: Why this has to be included? I am not able to understand.

Comment: This is a WP builtin function, which adds necessary information and files from wordpress core.

Comment: Ohh okay.. Thanks.. Will dig more about it.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can make it programatically through functions.php

First, create a function that includes the path to your favicon

```
 function add_favicon() {
      $favicon_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'your_path';
      echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="' . $favicon_url . '" />';
 }
```

Now, just *make sure* that function runs when you're on the login page and admin pages:

```
add_action('login_head', 'add_favicon');
add_action('admin_head', 'add_favicon');
```